# object oriented development in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Created a api server by using nodejs. as a habit from frontend development, developed them in object oriented structure but i'm confused in one point while writing.

```
var server = {
component: {
    http: require("http"),
    fs: require("fs")
},
start: function () {
    var instance=this;
    this.component.http.createServer(function (request, response) {
        instance.component.fs.readFile(filename, "binary", function (err, file) {
            // do something with file
        });
    }).listen(80);
}
```

That's my method to call inherited object within parameter function. in this case is single filesystem object sharing with all connections or do i need create a new filesystem instance for each new connection?

edit: "instance" is not a labeled statement.

Comment: what is object oriented about this?

Comment: `instance` is not defined anywhere in your code. Maybe mean `server.instance`, but that doesn't refer to `server` itself either. I'd recommend to read the MDN documentation about `this` and objects first.

Comment: I think that instead of `instance: this;` you really want `var instance = this;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example filesystem object will be reused for each connection.

**Advice regarding style of coding:** I am pretty sure you don't need 'instance' labeled statement - in fact I would strongly discourage you from using it in js at all! Labeled statements are usually used with break or continue statements & in fact have seen them in use only few times in my whole career. They make mess in code & can confuse someone who is reading your code. You can read more about label statements [in MDN JavaScript manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).

As a replacement of label here use e.g. variable. Also if you will start assigning 'this' to e.g. variable (or label in your example) try to stick to that & immediately start referring to this variable - try not to mix 'this' & variable containing it (like in line 8 of your code). Your code can then look like this:

```
var server = {
component: {
    http: require("http"),
    fs: require("fs")
},
start: function () {
    var instance = this;
    instance.component.http.createServer(function (request, response) {
        instance.component.fs.readFile(filename, "binary", function (err, file) {
            // do something with file
        });
    }).listen(80);
}
```

Object scope will isolate 'instance' here & allow it deeper in 'instance.component.http.createServer' callback.

Hope this answer & advices will help you & other JavaScript devs!